# Did Lars Andersen perform the stunts in "A new level of archery"?

Tags: video

[So lately i've discovered a Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEG-ly9tQGk) which went incredibly viral (20 mil views in a week). It's an amateurish filmed video called "A new level of archery" about the Danish archer Lars Andersen.

Now I have to admit that the stunts look impressive and somewhat real but it's possible to manipulate everything in videos which is why I'm wondering about whether these stunts were actually performed or not. Maybe CG or other tricks were used.

Are the stunts real? Some things just look almost impossible like splitting an arrow in two while on the move or catching an arrow mid-air while firing it before landing.

Comment: I really want this video to be challenged here, but it is currently too broad. We need to focus on one claim. e.g. Can Andersen split an arrow on the move, without fakery? or (even better) Is the placement of the arrow on the left (?) side of the bow a technique widely used in history, but forgotten since the introduction of firearms?

Comment: Note: the title is too broad. Do you mean the film-makers somehow cheated? Do you mean Lars Andersen is hoaxing them/us? Or could it be that he is genuine, but merely wrong? Or some combination of these. Or completely correct.

Comment: @Oddthinking Hmm I'm trying to fix this and I'll get the second question into a seperate one (the historical one).

Comment: Criticism of archery claims here:  http://geekdad.com/2015/01/danish-archer/

I think the "catching the arrow mid-flight" stunt might be the easiest to debunk: Mythbusters did a very solid bust of it and, while that might not be enough, the math just doesn't work out (time of transit / reaction time, etc.) Plus, it doesn't require knowledge of advanced archery skills, just superhuman reflexes.

Comment: While it's less than scientific proof, Snopes has an article on this http://www.snopes.com/info/news/larsandersen.asp where Lars admits that it took several takes for some of the tricks, and others involved using lightweight (slow) bamboo arrows.

Comment: [This article](http://www.odditycentral.com/news/real-life-legolas-uses-ancient-techniques-to-shoot-arrows-even-faster-than-tolkiens-elven-archer.html) says `This guy is so incredibly good with the bow and arrow he doesn’t even compete in archery tournaments. They’re just not challenging enough for him.`  Assuming that's an actual paraphrase, I find that a red flag.  If he competed, won easily, then stopped, that'd be one thing, but if he doesn't even bother competing...  I *want* to believe, though.

Comment: @LarryOBrien I actually remember thinking, "Hmm, this guy reminds me of Star Wars Kid," while watching the video, and sure enough, your linked article says the same thing.

Comment: This video is so funny to watch because he just looks awkward in every move. I don't doubt the fast shooting, I only doubt his accuracy while shooting fast. Catching the arrow, sure it's possible with the right arrow going not at full speed. Even the part where he hit the pop can flap thing is doable by just about anyone, all you have to do is record the one time that you hit it. This video looks like a comedic take on archery than anything else

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff - That article was already linked to earlier in the comments.